# Border around CSS Grid item div

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to make a border around the entire div of a CSS grid Item, rather than around the text itself.

CSS:

```
.grid-parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

.bordered-grid-item {
  border: 1px black dashed;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-parent">
  <div class="bordered-grid-item ">
    Column 1
  </div>
  <div>
    Column 1
  </div>
</div>
```

FIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/tpr4ydjx/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the item ocupy the whole space with width: 100%

```css
.grid-parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

.bordered-grid-item {
  border: 1px black dashed;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-parent">
  <div class="bordered-grid-item ">
    Column 1
  </div>
  <div>
    Column 1
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's either you add padding for your `.bordered-grid-item` like below

```
.bordered-grid-item {
  border: 1px black dashed;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

or the whole on `.grid-parent`

```
.grid-parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  border: 1px black dashed;
  padding: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
}
```

it depends on what you want.